# Cloning a VM with always on and use the backup for database restoration

Tags: sql-server

I just need your help on this idea if applicable. We have two node always-on availability group setup. Came across that the current Primary Node is problematic and a lot of issue (disk issue).

The other issue is we could not also failover to secondary (Server has no issue) since the availability group is broken and we could not restore a recently log anymore since the tape containing the backup also broken on secondary node.

Our plan right now is to take a full backup and log backup on the Primary Node and join it into availability group in Secondary Node. But the issue is, our team is on worry to take a full backup on current Primary Node since we have a lot of transactions daily and taking the backup around 4TB will it a lot of IO and the Primary Node might go down. Also at night we still a lot of transactions.

First I will stop the transaction log backup on Primary Node

What we plan is to clone the current VM (Primary and Secondary) and put this clone server on separate domain or subnet. I will take a full backup on this clone server and on the Original Primary Node I will take a log backup. The Full backup (from clone server) and log backup(original server) will be restore in Secondary Node with no recovery and I will join it into availability Group. With this we can avoid IO issue on the current primary node.

Is this current setup advisable? Thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> What we plan is to clone the current VM (Primary and Secondary) and put this clone server on separate domain or subnet.

Depending on how that is accomplished may or may not work. If the VM is shut down, it should work. If the VM is online and the cloning process does not use VSS integration, or doesn't stun the VM to get a steady state, then again this will not work.

Otherwise, everything is else fine and normal.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but my worry is taking the full backup from clone vm and restoring it on secondary node on our production.

Comment: I thought you were doing this to get around the bad IO subsystem on the primary? What's your concern?